# allow db communication over internal ip

Tags: iptables

So i have a webserver and a (Mysql) database server. Both have 2 interfaces, 1 with a public ip and 1 with an internal IP.

I want these two to only communicate over the internal IP on the default MySQL port 3306.

Here's my iptables config from the database server:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *My HQ*        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *Internal IP webserver*        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
```

And here's the iptables on my webserver:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *ip nagios server*        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5666
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *My HQ*        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *My HQ*        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10081 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:36512 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *Internal IP Database server*        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:36512 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:465 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *Internal IP Database Server*        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
```

I've got MySQL bind on the internal IP aswell.

Yet when i try something as simple as:

```
mysql -h *internal ip db server* -u root -p
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '*internal db server ip*' (110)
```

Is there anything i'm forgetting or is there anything wrong with the IPTABLES set up?

I'm using a CentOS 7.2.1511 machine and MySQL version 5.7.

Note: It could very well be there's more than one issue with this iptables config. as i'm just experimenting with this in order to learn.

Comment: iptables rules are checked in order so your db connection might hit your drop rules. Move your 3306 accept port rule before the drops.

Comment: I just removed the drop lines i had in but i'm still not able to connect.
But i kept the drop policy on the INPUT chain in place. Could that be giving issues ?

Comment: Start with no firewall settings and make sure your connection works. Then add the firewall rules.

Comment: These firewall rules are quite unreadable. `iptables-save -c` gives an output similar to the commands used to create the rules (while displaying counters too). Easier in a question.